# Replacing the end of a word with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of words that I need to replace the endings.

```
Regex reg = new Regex("(.+)ings");
word = reg.Replace(word,"thly");
```

I want then `abcdeings` => `abcdethly`

but I only get `thly`

Comment: That's because you're replacing everything in the string that matches the regex. Why not use the usula `string.Replace` method?

Comment: I only want the end replaced, not the beginning or middle where the string might appear.

Comment: Then you need to deal with regex groups. Look at this article, might help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `$` option at the end of the string, this signifies the end of a string, or alternatively, the `\b` option which signifies a word boundary

```
word = Regex.Replace(word, "ings$", "thly");
```

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Because I tested it and it doesn't work. `word = Regex.Replace(word, "ings\b", "thly");` still returns `abcdeings`

Comment: @AmirPopovich Adding an @ fixed it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `\b` delimiter:

```
string word = Regex.Replace("abcdeings",@"ings\b","thly");
```

Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html).

Answer (score 0):

The following regex pattern maches a position following a prefix

```
(?<=prefix)find\b
```

In our case we use `\w+` as prefix, which denotes one or more word characters

```
(?<=\w+)ings\b
```

This works because the prefix is not part of the selected text.

Comment: You could just use `\B` instead (not a word boundary). ie `\Bings\b`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski's idea is good and simple. `\Bings\b` works for me (.NET). Not a word ending before "ings" and a word ending after "ings".